# Smart array filtering JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, foreach, filtering

I got a very interesting task to do but end up with a bad code. It mutates initial array I want to avoid.

Here is an array example:

```
[
{
ID: "some id",
NAME: "some name",
PROPERTIES:
    [
        {
            TYPE: [{UF_NAME: "some type name"}]
        },
        {
            OTHER_TYPE:
                [
                    {UF_NAME: "some other type name"},
                    {UF_NAME: "some other type name"},
                ]
        },
        ...
    ],
...
OFFERS:
    [
        {
            ID: "some id",
            NAME: "some name",
            PROPERTIES:
                [
                    {
                        SIZE: [{UF_NAME: "some type name"}]
                    },
                    {
                        COLOR:
                            [
                                {UF_NAME: "some color 1"},
                                {UF_NAME: "some color 2"},
                            ]
                    },
                    ...
                ],
        },
        {
            ID: "some id",
            NAME: "some name",
            PROPERTIES:
                [

                ]
        },
        ...
    ]
},
...
```

]

Here is the result I am about to achieve without mutating initial array:

```
[
{
ID: "some id",
NAME: "some name",
PROPERTIES:
    [
        {
            TYPE: [{UF_NAME: "some type name"}]
        },
        {
            OTHER_TYPE:
                [
                    {UF_NAME: "some other type name"},
                    {UF_NAME: "some other type name"},
                ]
        },
        ...
    ],
...
OFFERS:
    [
        {
            ID: "some id",
            NAME: "some name",
            PROPERTIES:
                [
                    {
                        SIZE: [{UF_NAME: "some type name"}]
                    },
                    {
                        COLOR:
                            [
                                {UF_NAME: "some color 1"},
                                {UF_NAME: "some color 2"},
                            ]
                    },
                    ...
                ],
        }
    ]
}
```

]

What filter should do:

1. Go through whole array searching **values** in object properties and offers properties
2. Return a new copy of initial array with filtered offers

Array structure:

Product 1
-- Offer 11
-- Offer 12
-- Offer 13

Product 2
-- Offer 21
-- Offer 22
-- Offer 23

Product 3
-- Offer 31
-- Offer 32
-- Offer 33

Filtered array structure:

Product 1
-- Offer 11

Product 2
-- Offer 23

Product 3
-- Offer 31

Here is my function:

```
function filter (array, filter) {
        return array.filter(function iter(o) {
            return Object.keys(o).some(function (k) {
                if (typeof o[k] === 'string' && o[k].indexOf(filter) !== -1) {
                    return true
                }
                if (Array.isArray(o[k])) {
                    o[k] = o[k].filter(iter)
                    return o[k].length
                }
            })
        })
    }
```

Comment: The `filter` function doesn't mutate the original array. Try using that, and if you have problems, ask a question about those problems.

Comment: Dear @Heretic Monkey, thank you for your replay! I've just updated my question. Function that mutates initial array at the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rewrite the code to avoid fiter with a nested filter and reassignment of properties.

This function reduce the array and checks the properties if a wanted property is found, a new property is added to a temporary object and later pushed to the result set.

Same goes for nested arrays, these are reduced as well, because of a possible nested structure.

```
function filter(array, filter) {
    return array.reduce(function iter(r, o) {
        var temp = {};

        Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
            if (typeof o[k] === 'string' && o[k].indexOf(filter) !== -1) {
                temp[k] = o[k];
            } else if (Array.isArray(o[k])) {
                var filtered = o[k].reduce(iter, []);
                if (filtered.length) temp[k] = filtered;
            }
        });

        if (Object.keys(temp).length) r.push(temp);

        return r;
    }, []);
}
```